# Why this code doesn't work in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer-8

I am having trouble runing this piece of code in IE8. I am not really sure, what is the reason, but it seems, that the browser doesn't load javascript at all. All of the recent browser run it perfectly, unfortunately the code takes part of a project which needs to be supported also in IE8.

I'll be looking forward to any help, thanks.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>css demo</title>
<style>
html{
overflow: hidden;
}
body{
background: url("pattern.jpg");
}
a{
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
display: inline-block;
}
div{
width: 262px;
height: 262px;
display: inline-block;
position: absolute;
}
div:hover{
opacity: 0.5;
z-index: 10;
}
#square11{
width: 262px;
height: 324px;
background: url("square11.png");
top:-200px;
left:-200px;
z-index: 1;
}
#square12{
width: 386px;
height: 262px;
background: url("square12.png");
top:-200px;
left:50%;
z-index: 2;
}
#square13{
width: 262px;
height: 324px;
background: url("square13.png");
top:-200px;
left:100%;
z-index: 3;
}
#square21{
width: 324px;
height: 262px;
background: url("square21.png");
top:100%;
left:-200px;
z-index: 4;
}
#square22{
width: 262px;
height: 324px;
background: url("square22.png");
top:100%;
left:50%;
z-index: 5;
}
#square23{
width: 324px;
height: 262px;
background: url("square23.png");
top:100%;
left:100%;
z-index: 6;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="square11">
<a href=""></a>
</div>

<div id="square12">
<a href=""></a>
</div>

<div id="square13">
<a href=""></a>
</div>

<div id="square21">
<a href=""></a>
</div>

<div id="square22">
<a href=""></a>
</div>

<div id="square23">
<a href=""></a>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
w = window.innerWidth / 2;
h = window.innerHeight / 2;

$("#square11").animate({'position': "absolute", 'top': h - 262, 'left': w - 393}, 1000);
$("#square12").animate({'position': "absolute", 'top': h - 262, 'left': w - 193}, 1000);
$("#square13").animate({'position': "absolute", 'top': h - 262, 'left': w + 131}, 1000);
$("#square21").animate({'position': "absolute", 'top': h - 2, 'left': w - 393}, 1000);
$("#square22").animate({'position': "absolute", 'top': h - 64, 'left': w - 131}, 1000);
$("#square23").animate({'position': "absolute", 'top': h - 2, 'left': w + 68}, 1000);
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Create jsfiddle that reproduce this issue.

Comment: Why are you loading jQuery twice?

Comment: @Barmar - It's just in case, better to be safe than sorry !

Comment: Because it's IE8. Microsoft had dropped support, and so should you.

Comment: Did you try the debugger?

Comment: Please don't use jQuery library twice like that.

Comment: @Barmar - obviously... what kind of question...

Comment: @mvw - lol, good one !

Comment: I've been able to convince two huge companies to forget about it, you can too. Just show them the facts.

Comment: I'm sorry @adeneo, but that's made my day. hahaha

Comment: I think people may have jumped the gun too quickly to downvote this post. Looking at the JS makes it quite evident that the JS in use isn't supported by IE8. Just a thought.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because `window.innerHeight` and `window.innerWidth` doesn't work in IE8 and earlier as stated [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_innerheight.asp).

You can use `$(window).height()` and `$(window).width()`.

Answer (score 0):

**IE8** doesn't support the `window.innerHeight` and `window.innerWidth` properties.

Use the following equivalents:

```
var w = document.body.clientWidth / 2;
var h = document.body.clientHeight / 2;
```

Comment: In theory this works. Anyway in this case the variable h returns 0, because, there's nothing else in body than absolutelly positionned divs.